# Ajax open(post) does not update the file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a html page that saves some data on a server file (upated_data.php). I have follow the instructions to do so using AJAX, but the server file remains unchanged. Could you help me to find the problem in the following code, please?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head><title>test</title></head>
 <body>
  <script>
   var data = '{"data": "..."}';
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = warn_saving;
   xmlhttp.open("POST","updated_data.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(data);
   function warn_saving() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The files I have on the server side are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  493 jun  5 15:42 test.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    1 jun  5 15:43 updated_data.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You **claim** you are posting form data, but you are actually posting JSON, so I'd expect problems. It is your server side code that is responsible for updating the file though, and you haven't shared that with us so we can't tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sooooo muuuuuchhh coooode when all it would take with jQuery would be `$.post('updated_data.php',data).success( function(res){ alert(res); })` - @Quentin OP is posting a STRING (stringified json) - maybe that's why nothing happens. @Franpena what's your server-side code? (updated_data.php) ?

Comment: Well, I have checked the json case, changing two lines in the code:     xmlhttp.open("POST","updated_data.json",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
But still does not work. I cannot send you the url page because I am in a test server with no public connection, sorry.

Comment: @JeremyThille — Clearly adding 84 kilobytes of jQuery would be less code. And I said it was JSON and that might be the cause, but that we would need to see the server side code to tell.

Comment: @franpena — I have no idea how you checked the json case or what "echangThe" means. The issue stands though - your server side code matters.

Comment: @JeremyThille, what I posted is the test.html file on server side. I am using d3 instead of jQuery because the rest of the web page heavily uses svg, where jQuery has drawbacks.

Comment: @franpena: post updated_data.php

Comment: @Quentin, of course, if it's just to make one call, no need for the whole library. But jQuery makes life easier, not only here, but in the whole app. I was just amazed how it can reduce so much code to a simple line. I don't imagine writing a whole app in pure javascript.

Comment: @Cagatay Ulubay, post updated_data.php is empty, as it is at the beginning.

Comment: An awful lot of what jQuery does can be done pretty simply with modern JS and browser APIs. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: @franpena — updated_data.php is empty? Why would you expect a program with no code in it to update your file?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to save the data INTO the fiupdated_data.php file? AJAX helps you to do a server-side request to be able to do such actions in the background without to reload the page and on the fly. In your PHP file you have to take out the data and perform the actions to 1. create a file, 2. fill in the data into the file, 3. safe/close the file

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for the suggestion, but I am not the guy who chose the rules to write the web page, so Jquery is not an option right now.

Comment: @franpena — I was arguing *against* adding jQuery

Comment: Wow, I think Cagatay is right, OP is trying to write into the PHP file - @Franpena, that's now how it works at all... You call the PHP file that contains PHP code, you pass it data and it will save the data somewhere (database...) you don't write into the file directly

Comment: @Cagatay Ulubay, I missed that point! I will rewrite the code with your idea and I will post it ASAP.

Comment: I wrote an answer to it, maybe it can lead to help you beeing successfull.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put the data inside the file, this is not what AJAX actually do.

If you want to add the data into a file, you have to do it with PHP like:

```
$handle = fopen( 'path/to/file.txt', 'w' );
fwrite( $handle, $data );
fclose( $handle );
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fopen.asp

You maybe have to change the `$data` var to represent the way it should be saved into your file. Also maybe you want the change the second `mode` parameter which describes what to do with the file and where to set the pointer:

w Mode = Write only and set Pointer to the **BEGINNING**, create file if not existing, otherwise remove the whole content.

Your data: Hello World

```
THIS IS A TEXT
^
```

becomes

```
Hello World
^
```

a Mode = Write only and set Pointer to the **END** of the file. If file not exist, create it.

Your data: Hello World

```
THIS IS A TEXT
              ^
```

becomes

```
THIS IS A TEXTHello World
                         ^
```

I hope you understand that I can't put the whole answer to the thing for you, but this should greatly helped you out to find the real way to do it and learning to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the previous suggestions, I believe I've got the right code. Now test.html calls PHP code stored in updated_data.php, :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head><title>test</title></head>
 <body>
  <script>
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("POST","updated_data.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   }
   var d = '{datos: cosa}'; 
   xmlhttp.send('data='+d);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And updated_data.php save updated_data.json:

```
<?php
   $v = $_POST['data'];
   file_put_contents('updated_data.json', json_encode($v));
?>
```